# Recent Update Broke "Songs" Package

Tags: songs

PS: *I hate to bump this, but I really need to revisit this issue. What are my options at this point? Can I temporarily use an older version of latex (how?), or some alternative version of packages other than `songs`?*

---

I am using the `songs` [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/songs) to typeset a little booklet of songs and chords. This used to work fine, but when I tried to recompile the sources I had last worked on a few weeks ago, the layout was broken. Within the `\begin{songs}` environment, line breaks are treated verbatim. This still works in `lyric` mode. (See MWE below.) When I enable `chorded` mode, however, these line breaks are no longer respected.

I have marked line breaks in the source with a pilcrow ¶ to make the issue easier to see.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
%\usepackage[lyric]{songs}

\newindex{myindex}{index}

\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{myindex}

\beginsong{And Can It Be}
\beginverse
\[F]And \[F/A]can \[(C)]it \[F]be that \[Gm/B&]I \[C7]should \[F]gain¶
An \[B&]in\[C]terest \[F/A]in \[C/E]the \[C/G]Sav\[G7]ior's \[C]blood?¶
Died He \[F/C]for me, \[C] who \[F/A]caused \[F]His \[C]pain?¶
\endverse

\beginchorus
Amazing \[C]love! How \[C7/E]can it \[F]be¶
That \[B&]Thou, my \[F/A]God, \[Gm/B&]shouldst \[F/C]die \[C7]for \[F]me?
\endchorus
\endsong

\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

The `songs` package hasn't been updated since 2018, so I suspect something in the base `LaTeX` system must have changed, because this used to work fine until recently. I am on the very latest `TeX Live 2022`.

`lyric` mode (top) works, `chorded` mode (bottom) is freshly broken:

[image]

Comment: the package  redefines `\par` and `\@@par` and that clashes imho with the new para hooks (see ltpara-doc.pdf). Contact the author, they will have to adapt their package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have done so already, pointing him to this thread.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That being said, it sounds like something that could be easily patched on the user level.

Comment: @Gaussler well if you know a work-around, show it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don’t, as I haven’t studied the code. But if the package redefines `\par` in a way that crashes with the hook system, why not just re-patch `\par` the same way *using* the hook system? That’s all I was thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that LaTeX changed the `\obeylines` command. You can try this patch. The author has been notified, but I will also discuss if LaTeX should do a firstaid patch.

#### Update

We added a firstaid to latex. This firstaid can be used now with latex-dev and will be in the next release LaTeX release in june 23 (unless the package is updated).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
%\usepackage[lyric]{songs}

\newindex{myindex}{index}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\SB@obeylines{%
  \let\obeyedline\SB@par%
  \obeylines%
  \let\@par\SB@@par%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{myindex}

\beginsong{And Can It Be}
\beginverse
\[F]And \[F/A]can \[(C)]it \[F]be that \[Gm/B&]I \[C7]should \[F]gain¶
An \[B&]in\[C]terest \[F/A]in \[C/E]the \[C/G]Sav\[G7]ior's \[C]blood?¶
Died He \[F/C]for me, \[C] who \[F/A]caused \[F]His \[C]pain?¶
\endverse

\beginchorus
Amazing \[C]love! How \[C7/E]can it \[F]be¶
That \[B&]Thou, my \[F/A]God, \[Gm/B&]shouldst \[F/C]die \[C7]for \[F]me?
\endchorus
\endsong

\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried notifying the author when the issue first arose, but haven't heard back from him. Thank you, Ulrike, your efforts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry it took a while for me to revisit this project, so I have just now verified and accepted your answer. This patch is exactly what I needed (even with TL 2023, BTW) and I am very grateful for that.

Answer (score 1):

I use *songs package* with Texlive with no problems.  With Miktex, I see the problem you have.
An alternative, it is to use *leadsheets package*.  It is more flexible than songs package, but you need to create your own template to take advantage of all customization capabilities.
Here is a working example for you to start

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\definesongtitletemplate{custom}{
    \ifsongmeasuring
    {\section*}
    {\section*}{%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.05\textwidth}p{0.95\textwidth}}
    \toprule
    \noindent{\color{blue!50}1}&{\songproperty{title}}\\
\end{tabular} 
\vskip -0.15\baselineskip%
\begingroup\normalfont\footnotesize
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{0.05\textwidth}p{0.95\textwidth}}
    \ifsongproperty{interpret}%
        {&  \GetTranslation{leadsheets/interpret}\\}
        {}% 
    \ifsongproperty{composer}%
        {&  \GetTranslation{leadsheets/composer}
            \printsongpropertylist{composer}{ \& }{, }{ \& }
            \\}
        {}%
    \ifsongproperty{lyrics}%
        {&  \GetTranslation{leadsheets/lyrics}
            \printsongpropertylist{lyrics}{ \& }{, }{ \& }
            \\}
        {}% 
    \ifsongproperty{key}
        {& \setchords{
             major = -\GetTranslation{leadsheets/major} ,
             minor = -\GetTranslation{leadsheets/minor}
             }%
         \GetTranslation{leadsheets/key}: %
         \expandcode{\writechord{\songproperty{key}}} \\%
         }
     {}%
    \midrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup    
    }
}

\setleadsheets{verse/numbered=true, align-chords = {l}}
\setleadsheets{print-chords=true, title-template=custom, chorus*/format = \bfseries}
\setchords{format={\color{blue}\sffamily\small\bfseries\itshape}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{song}[verse/numbered, remember-chords]{
            title={Reprehenderit in Voluptate Velit},
            interpret={Copycat},
            composer={inspired by others},
            music={No One Knows},
            lyrics={John Doe},
            key={Car Keys}
        }
        \begin{chorus*}
            LOR^{E}EM ipsum dolor sit A^{A}MET, consect^{B7}etur ADIPIS^*{E}CING \\
            elit, ^{A}sed do eiusmod tempor ^{B7}incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a^{E}liqua LOR^{E}EM ipsum dolor sit A^{A}MET, consect^{B7}etur ADIPIS^*{E}CING 
        \end{chorus*}
        
        \begin{verse}
            Lor^{E}em ipsum dolor sit A^{A}MET, consect^{B7}etur adipis^*{E}cing \\
elit, ^{A}sed do eiusmod tempor ^{B7}incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a^{E}liqua LOR^{E}EM ipsum dolor sit A^{A}met, consect^{B7}etur adipis^*{E}cing 
        \end{verse}
        
        \begin{verse}
            Lor^{E}em ipsum dolor sit A^{A}MET, consect^{B7}etur adipis^*{E}cing \\
elit, ^{A}sed do eiusmod tempor ^{B7}incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a^{E}liqua LOR^{E}EM ipsum dolor sit A^{A}met, consect^{B7}etur adipis^*{E}cing
        \end{verse}
    \end{song}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion; I will keep it in mind for future projects. This one has gone too far, however, to change LaTeX classes mid-stream, as it were :-)