# Songs package - line breaks in first verse with chords not correct

Tags: songs

I have a songbook based on the songs package. I migrated to the latest version of MikTex 22.12.
Now the first verse no longer looks well. The last line of the first verse has a negative indent, and the same for the chorus. It seems to be related to the chords, because other verses that don't contain chords look fine:

[image]

Here is the code that produces the picture above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\title{Songs package test}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{}


\beginsong{Soon may the Wellerman come}
[
by = {Unknown author, written ca. 1860--1870}
]
\index{The Wellerman}
\index{Wellerman}
\capo{3}    

\beginverse
There \[a]once was a ship that put to sea,
the \[d]name of the ship was the \[a]``Billy of Tea''.
The \[a]winds blew up, her bow dipped down,
oh \[E]blow, my bully boys, \[a]blow!
\endverse

\beginchorus
\[F]Soon may the \[C]Wellerman come
to \[d]bring us sugar and \[a]tea and rum.
\[F]One day, when the \[C]tonguin' is done,
we'll \[E]take our leave and \[a]go.
\endchorus
 
\beginverse
She'd not been two weeks from shore
when down on her a right whale bore.
The captain called all hands and swore
he'd take that whale in tow.
\endverse

\beginverse
Before the boat had hit the water
the whale's tail came up and caught her.
All hands to the side, harpooned and fought her
when she dived down low.
\endverse

\endsong

\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Temporary hack: switch back to an older kernel, e.g. `\RequirePackage[2022/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{scrartcl} ...`

Comment: compile with pdflatex-dev, we inserted a firstaid there to repair this. Alternatively, use the patch from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666610/2388

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I continue for the time being with the temporary hack from @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz