# Print with different size different pieces of the same chord

Tags: songs

I have been searching for one week to setup a macro in LaTeX/Songs in order to print with different size different pieces of the same chord (slash chord must be of smaller size) like this:

[image]

I've tried tons of things like this but everything fails ( the major failure is due to `\printchord` macro and `stringstring` packet doesn't have good feeling). Thanks for any help.

As asked here the final code example:

```
\newcounter{pos_slash}%
\renewcommand{\printchord}[1]{%
\setcounter{pos_slash}{0}%
\rmfamily\bf\normalsize%
\whereischar[q]{#1}{/}%
\theresult\par%
\ifthenelse{\expandafter\theresult>0}{%
\addtocounter{pos_slash}{\expandafter\theresult}
\addtocounter{pos_slash}{-1}}{}%
\setcounter{pos_slash}{3}}
\large\arabic{pos_slash}\par
\expandafter\substring[q]{\mystring}{1}{\expandafter\theresult}
\ifthenelse{\expandafter\theresult=0}{#1}{%
\substring[q]{#1}{1}{\arabic{pos_slash}}%
\addtocounter{pos_slash}{2}%
\tiny\slash\substring[q]{#1}{\arabic{pos_slash}}{13}}%
}
```

Comment: it would help if you provided a small example document that makes the output shown but without the size change, for those of us not familiar with `songs` package.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Marco, I've just read your question, maybe I'm a little late.
Anyway, here it is the code that I use for printing bass notes in smaller font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\notenamesin{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}           
\notenamesout{La}{Si}{Do}{Re}{Mi}{Fa}{Sol}  
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650106/recent-update-broke-songs-package/666610#666610
%necessary on TL2023
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\SB@obeylines{%
  \let\obeyedline\SB@par%
  \obeylines%
  \let\@par\SB@@par%
}
\makeatother

%my hit for bass fonts
\makeatletter
\def\bassfont{\futurelet\next\@bassverify}
\def\@basstrue{\hspace{-0.2em}/\hspace{-0.05em}\scriptsize}
\def\@bassfalse{/}
\def\@bassverify{%
  \ifcat\next f
    \@basstrue
  \else
    \@bassfalse
  \fi}

\renewcommand{\chordlocals}{%
\catcode`/\active}
{\chordlocals\global\let/\bassfont}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Maria, ora che sei qui}
\beginchorus
\[C]Tu Ma\[G/B]ria, tu \[F/A]sei, 
di\[E]mora \[E/G#]per Ge\[A-]su figlio \[A-/G]tuo, \[F7+]
re\[E]gina che dal \[A-]cie\[A-/G]lo, 
spe\[F7+]ran\[E]za, e a\[A-]mo\[A-/G]re ci \[F]dai. \[G]
\endchorus
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: This code comes from an answer of Enrico Gregorio to a request of mine on guitex.org (https://guitex.org/home/en/forum/5-tex-e-latex/74621-songs-modifica-catcode)